# How to filter item before loading them in isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I'm using isotope's filter function. I wrote:

```
$('#stage').isotope({
    filter:selector
});
```

in two places:

```
$(window).load(function() --> so
    that when users type url with
    hash(#), they can see the content
    items which is filtered out already.

$('.filters
    a').click(function(){filter:selector}); --> when users click particular link.
```

The problem is that whenever one clicks link which hash or type the url with hash, the browser will load all of the items first and later on filtering it out. What I want is: The page load only filtered items.

Comment: What's "selector"?  This is really hard to understand.

Comment: Also that second thing, with the ".filters a", the "click" handler isn't a proper function at all.

Comment: Hi sorry for unclear question. I actually found out how to fix it. Previously, I have both $(window).load(function() and $(document).ready. Both of them have $('#stage').isotope. So my solution is having filter:selector only if window.location has hash.

Comment: the click function is actually like this $('.filters a').click(function(){
 var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
 $('#stage').isotope({
  filter:selector
 });

});